# biblatex: how to print "de Haan (1970)" in the text but "Haan, L. de (1970)" in the references?

Tags: biblatex

As described in the MWE below, I'd like to have `de Haan (1970)` printed in the text and `Haan, L. de (1970)` in the references. How can one adjust the label in the text without changing the label in the references (or the other way round)? (only for a single reference, all others should not be changed)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{bib.bib}
@article{deHaan,
  author =   {Haan, L. {de}},
  title =    {On Regular Variation and its Application to the Weak
                  Convergence of Sample Extremes},
  note =     {Thesis, Mathematical Centre Tract, vol.\ 32, University of
                  Amsterdam},
  year =     1970
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\begin{document}
The reference \cite{deHaan} appears as ``Haan (1970)'' in the text and as ``Haan, L. de (1970)'' in the references below.
How can I get ``de Haan  (1970)'' in the text (while keeping ``Haan, L. de (1970)'' in the references) for just this one
reference (not all others potentially appearing)?

(This is the personal choice of this author and it is not too confusing to find the right reference even if the label
is different in the text (so one can justify that they differ). I saw the biblatex field shorthand, but that works differently)
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way to input a name with a *tussenvoegsel* ("von part"/name prefix) is

```
author = {de Haan, L.},
```

The form `author = {Haan, L. {de}},` will parse the `{de}` as an additional given name with no real chance of recovering that the "de" is a *tussenvoegsel*.

With the `de` correctly parsed as name prefix you can either set the option `useprefix` to `true` or `false`. If set to `true`, the name prefix will be treated as part of the family name (de Haan, L.), if `false` it is treated as part of the given name (Haan, L. de). If you want a mixture of the two you need to get creative. For that it helps to know that the `biblatex` side of that option is implemented as a toggle called `blx@useprefix`. You can change the value of this toggle whenever you want. Compare [Biblatex handling of Dutch "van" prefix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/226893/35864).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, useprefix=false]{biblatex}

\AtEveryCitekey{\toggletrue{blx@useprefix}}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@phdthesis{deHaan,
  author = {de Haan, L.},
  title  = {On Regular Variation and its Application to the Weak
            Convergence of Sample Extremes},
  school = {University of Amsterdam},
  year   = 1970,
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
The reference \autocite{deHaan}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: The reference (de Haan 1970)//Haan, L. de (1970). “On Regular Variation and its Application to the Weak Convergence of Sample Extremes”. PhD thesis. University of Amsterdam.]

Note that the global option influences sorting. The toggle `blx@useprefix` has no effect on sorting.

Comment: Thanks, interesting. I had to add `\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{inlinetext}{\textcite}{\textcites}` and `\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{autocite=inlinetext}` from your post `https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/474311/how-to-cite-with-only-year-inside-brackets-and-not-both-name-year` to get the `textcite` behavior.