# Dispaying Dutch surnames correctly in Harvard style using biber

Tags: biblatex, harvard-style, dutch

I'm having issues referencing Dutch authors using the Harvard citation system. Here you can see the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{filecontents*}{refs.bib}
@article{vanderVelden2007,
author = {van der Velden, Daniel},
journal = {Art Papers},
pages = {36--43},
title = {{Article One}},
volume = {31},
year = {2007}
}
@article{vanHoven2018,
author = {van Hoven, Bettina},
doi = {10.17169/fqs-19.2.2961},
journal = {Forum Qualitative Sozialforschung},
number = {2},
title = {{Creative and Arts}},
volume = {19},
year = {2018}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\begin{document}
\title{Article Title} \author{} \date{}
\maketitle

In that regard, \textcite[30]{vanderVelden2007} is correct.

The information was correctly interpreted \parencite[30]{vanHoven2018}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

In the text, the correct way to display the cited authors would be:

- In that regard, Van der Velden (2007, pág. 30) is correct.
- The information was correctly interpreted (Van Hoven 2018, pág. 30}.

Note: "van" and "van der" should be capitalised when the first name is not included.

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/464833/35864.

Comment: Depending on your sorting preferences you may or may not want to combine this with setting `useprefix` globally or something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/610091/35864.

Comment: Thanks @moewe, but that example is using biblatex, whereas I'm using biber.

Comment: You *are* using `biblatex` (your code has `\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid,backend=biber]{biblatex}`). `biblatex` is the package on the LaTeX side that implements bibliography and citation commands (like `natbib`). Biber is the backend that reads the `.bib` file and produces a LaTeX-readable bibliography data (like BibTeX). See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 for a more thorough explanation of what each component does.

Comment: Any news here? Did the links above help? Did you have any trouble implementing the suggestions (if so, what did you try and how did it not work for you?)?

Comment: Oh, thanks for the follow-up. This worked for my document: \AtEveryCitekey{\toggletrue{blx@useprefix}}